# what is the difference between BIO_read/BIO_write and SSL_read/SSL_write when the BIOs are memory BIOs and not socket BIOs?

Tags: openssl, webrtc, dtls

I am confused about the difference between the BIO routines `BIO_read()`/`BIO_write()` and the `SSL_read()`/`SSL_write()` when the BIOs are memory BIOs and not socket BIOs.

I am trying to code a WebRTC server using `libnice` for the ICE stack and OpenSSL for the DTLS stack. The ICE stack has the socket connection to the client so I cannot use the socket-based BIOs in OpenSSL. Instead, I am using the memory BIOs.

So the high level procedure I am using is that, when I receive the DTLS messages from the client on the ICE socket, I write that message to the DTLS stack using `BIO_write()`. Then when the DTLS stack has a message to send to the client I get that message using the `BIO_read()` and send it to the client using the ICE socket.

I have seen some examples of source code that does essentially this procedure, but they also call the `SSL_read()` routine after the `BIO_write()` call. This makes no sense to me. Why is the call to `SSL_read()` necessary after I essentially have written the client message into the DTLS stack using the `BIO_write()` call?  If I do not call `SSL_read()` after the `BIO_write()` my code does not work. But when I call `SSL_read()` after the `BIO_write()`, this is indeed exchanging the handshake messages with the browser client.

**Question**: Using memory BIOs, what is the difference between `BIO_read()` and `SSL_read()`?

**Question**: Using memory BIOs, what is the difference between `BIO_write()` and `SSL_write()`?

**Question**: Is the default memory BIO blocking or non-blocking?  I am assuming it is non-blocking since it is a memory-based BIO and not a socket-base BIO.

Thanks,
-Andres

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem with understanding how the whole thing works. I can provide you with some useful links and cites.

"*The SSL layer is setup to work in buffer mode. So doing SSL_write means we're sending unencrypted bytes to the SSL library, so that it can encrypt these bytes and put the resulting encrypted bytes in a buffer. Then we read from the buffer using BIO_read. Same thing in reverse for reading. We ACTUALLY do BIO_write then SSL_read in that case.*"

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/8Ulf_G5kpyA

**OpenSSL data handling** - check this part from link below. It might give you some useful information.
https://famellee.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/use-openssl-with-io-completion-port-and-certificate-signing/

**BIOs** - check this part from link below. It might give you some useful information.
http://www.roxlu.com/2014/042/using-openssl-with-memory-bios